# Write a PL/SQL code to calculate the power of 2 for numbers (1-10)?

Tags: oracle, function, loops, plsql

How can I Write a PL/SQL **code** to calculate the power of 2 for numbers (1-10)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Seems to be a question of some exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [power](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions112.htm) SQL function

```
select rownum rn, power(2, rownum) pwr
from dual
connect by level <= 10;

        RN        PWR
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          4
         3          8
         4         16
         5         32
         6         64
         7        128
         8        256
         9        512
        10       1024

10 rows selected
```

Comment: "I want a pl/sql code"   SO is not a free code-writing service.  Show us your best effort, then others can point out what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL it is - a function which uses a loop to calculate the result.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_power (n in number)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number := 2;
  5  begin
  6    for i in 2 .. n loop
  7      retval := retval * 2;
  8    end loop;
  9    return retval;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select level as n, f_power(level) result
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 10;

         N     RESULT
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          4
         3          8
         4         16
         5         32
         6         64
         7        128
         8        256
         9        512
        10       1024

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE does it.

```
with  pows( n, pown) as 
     (  select 1, 2 from dual 
         union all 
        select n+1, pown*2 
          from pows
         where n<&N
     )
select * from pows;
```